# ng-boostrap typeahead for array of objects

Tags: angular

Happy Holidays people,

I being trying to apply typeahead for array object type that I get from the server:

```
  data=[{name:'HP',id:1}......]

search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$ 
      .debounceTime(200)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .map(term => {
        const matchRegExp = new RegExp(term, 'gi');
        return term.length === 0 ? [] : this.ar_items_manfs.filter(v => {

          return this.selectedItems.indexOf(v) === -1 && matchRegExp.test(v);
        });
      });


  selected($e) {
    $e.preventDefault();
    this.selectedItems.push($e.item);
    console.log($e);
    console.log('--------');
    this.inputEl.nativeElement.value = '';
  }

  close(item) {
    this.selectedItems.splice(this.selectedItems.indexOf(item), 1);
    this.inputEl.nativeElement.focus();
  }
```

I have followed [this plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/sZNw1lO2y3ZZR0GxLyjD?p=preview), which works fine for arrays. For now, my hack is not nice. I am taking the "name" from each and build a new array then get the id back if it is clicked.

Is there away to do the above plunkr for objects of the above type.

Comment: Go to the official example page (https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples), and look at the "Template for results" example. If I understand correctly, it does what you wantto do. If not, please elaborate on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: just change the "filter" comparing the "name" property: filter(v => v. **name** .toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()

Comment: Thanks guys. Took pieces from both and it is now awesome. Happy new year!